# Having issues getting livejs.com

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having some issues getting the livejs.com script to automatically update web pages for changes made to HTML/CSS/Javascript. Below is my HTML on my localhost and it points to the web location of the script, which is accurate. Can you help me understand why my web pages don't update when I save my html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title-Sam</title>
  <script type="text/script" src="http://livejs.com/live.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <h1>My First Heading adfasdfadf this is cool</h1>

  <p>My first paragraph.</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Running this HTML from WebStorm IDE (served as http://localhost:63342/...), and it works.

Answer (score 3):

## Typo

> ```
> type="text/script"
> ```

This is not a format of script that browsers recognise. It should be `text/javascript`.

In HTML 5 you should omit the attribute entirely.

---

## Working locally

From the homepage:

> Just include Live.js and it will monitor the current page including local CSS and Javascript by sending consecutive HEAD requests to the server.

If you are working from a local file (i.e. without a web server) then there is nowhere to make the HEAD request to. You need to be testing using HTTP(S).

---

## Server support

The script checks a variety of headers, including `Etag` and `Last-Modified`. If your server doesn't set any of them for static files, it won't be able to tell when the file has updated.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful!